# scipy.hierarchy : Stop clustering beyond a threshold

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to perform clustering with the `scipy.hierarchy` module. I want to know if there is any way to stop clustering beyond a threshold value. On a small test array `(d=5X5 matrix)`, I used a complete linkage method to obtain the linkage array,

```
fc = hrc.linkage(d , method='complete')
```

Printing `fc` gave me the following,

```
0           1.          2.00706122      2.              
2           5.          2.49008944      3.            
3           4.          3.14776579      2.          
6           7.          3.67076599      5.
```

I want specify a threshold (say 2.5) so that the clustering will stop when that value is met. In the above case for instance the clustering is continued till a maximum threshold of 3.6.